# How to convert the MP4 video file from images without audio using FFMPEG?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am converting the MP4 video file `$output` from some images and one audio file.
But now I want to convert the same MP4 video file without audio.
How to do it?

Here is my sample code:

```
// Convert Video from audio and images
exec("$ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i $convImgPath -i $convAudioPath -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 16k -shortest $output");
```

Please update my code where I am change.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable audio via `-an` i.e.

```
exec("$ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i $convImgPath -i $convAudioPath -c:v libx264 -an -shortest $output");
```